anchor links and id combination for scrolling don't work for page reload and back and forward button of browser?
       <a
        href={getUrlHash(props.primaryCTA?.url)}
        className="btn btn--primary"
        target={props.primaryCTA?.target || ''}
        aria-label={props.primaryCTA?.title || ''}
        rel="noreferrer noopener"
      >
        <span>{parse(props.primaryCTA?.text || '')}</span>
      </a>`

When I click on an anchor link, the page scrolls to the specified section correctly. However, when I click the back button, the URL updates, but the page displays as blank. This issue also occurs with page reloads and the forward button.
why??
Expected Result: When I click on an anchor link, the page should scroll to the specific section. If I then click the back button, the page should scroll to the top. When I click the back button again, it should return me to the previous page.
Actual Result: When I click on an anchor link, the page correctly scrolls to the specific section. However, when I click the back button, the page scrolls to the top but displays a blank white page, which is not the desired behavior.

Can you please edit your code snippet to display the values of your functions and variables so that the steps can be reproduced?
